# AIX Script Call - Execution Delay

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, sh

I have a shell script A that calls another shell script B.

Somehow the shell script B being called takes a long time to actually start executing. Around 20 seconds or so.

I confirmed this by doing a echo `date` on the first line of the called shell script. What could be the issue? I am not sure what I could look at.

The call graph is simple

## Script A

```
echo "Just Started Executing A" `date`
. B
echo "Just Finished Executing A" `date`
```

## Script B

```
echo "Just Started Executing B" `date`
```

Output is

```
Just Started Executing A Thu Nov 20 02:31:33 ADT 2014
Just Started Executing B Thu Nov 20 02:31:58 ADT 2014
Just Finished Executing A Thu Nov 20 02:31:58 ADT 2014
```

I used time command to measure the time spent in calling just the script B and the distribution was like this.

```
real    0m25.56s
user    0m17.12s
sys     0m0.27s
```

I have confirmed that there is no shortage of CPU or Memory on the server.

```
| CPU-Utilisation-Small-View ==========qEntitledCPU=  7.00 UsedCPU=  2.609==============================================q|
|Logical  CPUs              0----------25-----------50----------75----------100                                          |
|CPU User%  Sys% Wait% Idle%|           |            |           |            |                                          |
|  0  21.5  22.0   0.0  56.5|UUUUUUUUUUsssssssssss            >               |                                          |
|  1  31.5  19.0   0.0  49.5|UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUsssssssss                         >                                          |
|  2  40.0  32.5   0.0  27.5|UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUssssssssssssssss      >      |                                          |
|  3  33.0   1.0   0.0  66.0|UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU                   >             |                                          |
|  4  21.5  27.5   0.0  51.0|UUUUUUUUUUsssssssssssss                     >    |                                          |
|  5  37.5   5.0   0.0  57.5|UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUss        >                    |                                          |
|  6   9.0  16.5   0.0  74.5|UUUUssssssss                                 >   |                                          |
|  7   0.5   4.5   0.0  95.0|ss                                      >        |                                          |
|  8   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0|                                     >           |                                          |
|  9   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0|                    >                            |                                          |
| 10   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0|                          >                      |                                          |
| 11   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0|  >                                              |                                          |
| 12   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0|                               >                 |                                          |
| 13   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0|>                                                |
```

Please guide.

Comment: Is it repeatable? Do you experience I/O congestion?

Comment: @tripleee There was no I/O Congestion but CPU usage of the process was on a higher side while it was trying to start up. Thanks for the tip. I have posted an answer on how we solved this issue. It was the history file that was huge and probably seek to the end of the file was what was causing the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems got resolved. Here is what I did to nail it.
When the process was taking long to start, i noted the PID of it. TO make it easier for me, it was showing up in the topas as the top process so I could get the PID without much problem.

I did a killl -6  to generate a core dump and to find out what the process is doing while it is taking so long. The core dump said this.

```
IOT/Abort trap in . at 0x10006c3c
0x10006c3c (???) 80410014         lwz   r2,0x14(r1)
(dbx) where
sh_done_15_8(??, ??) at 0x10006c3c
read(??, ??, ??) at 0xd0385ed4
io_readbuff(??) at 0x1000467c
**hist_eof() at 0x10016db4
hist_open() at 0x100173f4**
item(??) at 0x100247a0
term(??) at 0x10024ce8
list(??) at 0x10024bdc
sh_cmd(??, ??) at 0x10024e5c
sh_cmd(??, ??) at 0x10024f10
sh_parse(??, ??) at 0x10025970
sh_eval(??) at 0x1001bf10
b_dot(??, ??) at 0x1001ba60
xec_builtin(??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??) at 0x1001e24c
xec_switch(??, ??, ??, ??, ??) at 0x1001e760
sh_exec(??, ??, ??) at 0x10020078
exfile() at 0x10001750
main(??, ??) at 0x1000092c
```

Going by intuition, I checked the history file of the user and it was huge. Around 500 MB.

Deleted the history file and.... VOILA!!! The problem got resolved.